# How to copy fixed part of rows based on cell selection , Excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have table with many columns , I need if I select cells B3 or C3 (for example) to copy cells B3:G3 on the same row .

Selection can be any rows on the sheet. Is it possible to be done with vba ?
sample sheet is attached on this link
https://easyupload.io/8knzr9

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Select Row Range

- When selecting a range that contains cells in columns `B` and/or `C`, it will select their rows, but in columns `B:G`.
- It will not include the first two rows which contain merged cells.
- It will allow multiple non-contiguous selections.

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const cFirstRow As String = "B3:C3"
    Const sCols As String = "B:G"
    
    Dim crg As Range
    With Range(cFirstRow)
        Set crg = .Resize(Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(crg, Target)
    
    If Not irg Is Nothing Then
    
        Dim srg As Range, arg As Range, rrg As Range
        For Each arg In irg.Areas
            For Each rrg In arg.Rows
                If srg Is Nothing Then
                    Set srg = Columns(sCols).Rows(rrg.Row)
                Else
                    Set srg = Union(srg, Columns(sCols).Rows(rrg.Row))
                End If
            Next rrg
        Next arg
        
        If Not srg Is Nothing Then
            srg.Select
        End If
    
    End If
        
End Sub
```

Comment: It works perfectly. If I need to Copy , just modified srg.select. Into seg.copy. Many Great thanks  "VBasic2008" for your continuous help.